# width of GoogleMaps in table cell

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3, width

I'm trying to make a simple web interface with a table with two columns:

- Left: width 400px
- Right: the rest of avalaible width

I think that is very simple, but i can't do it. The more closer that I were from the success was with this code

HTML:

```
<table id="container">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20%">
            <div id="sidebar" style="z-index:1;"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 80%">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="z-index:10;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#map_canvas {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 99%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 99%;
    _height: 99%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

but always appears the horizontal scroll bar and the map overflows the width of the window

Thanks, and sorry about my bad english...

Answer (score 0):

The scroll is probably for the default margin of the body and also the border of your table. You can try this

HTML

```
<table id="container">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:400px">
            <div id="sidebar" style="z-index:1;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="map_canvas" style="z-index:10;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collpse;
  border:0 none;
}
```

Review this Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/pTZKa/**

**Edit**

As an asnwer for your commentary : That happens because you have `positon:absolute` so he is searching for his closest parent with a non absolute position declared to be positioned. To fix that add this on the css:

```
 table td {
    position:relative;
}
```

New Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/pTZKa/4/**

Comment: Thanks Danko, you resolved other problem that I had, but I still have overflow with the map. The problem is, how can I fill the 100% of the cell that the map is in? At the moment I can create a table like in your example, but if the left column has 300px width, the overflow is 300px...
I mean, i want a table 100% width, 300px on the left column and the rest in right... I'm very lost...

Comment: i don't undesrtand if you want 300px just change the value... now if the problem is the map inside i need to see all the code including the map can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I think that the problem is in the CSS of the div map_canvas, because I am able to create a table with 300px on the left column and the rest of avalaible width in the right column, but when I put the div map_canvas on the right column with this CSS:

    http://jsfiddle.net/XqSUq/2/
it grows to right because the div has width 99% of total width, and I want 99% of the total column width, that is to say, total width avalaible minus the 300px of the sidebar.

Thanks again!

Comment: It works fine for width!! But I want to put heigth to 100% and when I put it on the css I can't see anything when the page loads

Thanks for your useful help Danko!!

Comment: height 100% of the browsers size?

Comment: yes, instead of heigth: 500px (i.e.) heigth: 100%, but doesn't work